# command line tools for simplifying iptables?

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables

For example, something like htop. It's easy to use (it's almost got a "gui"). But it still runs on the command line.

Is there something that can simplify getting iptables working for me?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you have issues understanding iptables, try using only long command line arguments until you get used to it. This makes the rules longer, but much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**UFW**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) - Uncomplicated Firewall is Ubuntu's way of simplifying iptables.

Answer (score 2):

Look at shorewall.  Very good documentation, and default configurations for 1, 2, and 3 interfaces.  Good capability to show the state of the firewall.  Its available as a package, but you will need to do the initial configuration.

Comment: I used Shorewall for a long time and to be honest it doesnt help at all. You still need to learn shorewall itself and in my opinion it doesnt simplify anything maybe with one exception - if you have to configure really complex firewall on N interfaces - something like a routing between few networks ect. For desktop users Shorewall is definitely toooo complex.  UFW is the best choice here I think.

Comment: @Robert I've tried UFW and other tools like it and found they didn't handle anything beyond the simplest ON/OFF configuration with any ease.  They also didn't help in understanding what was happening.

Comment: In this case it's up to you. I think it's a matter of personal preferences. Long time I also was searching for a nice tool which would help me with setting up firewall. At the very end of this story I just learned iptables itself :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how "something like htop" relates to get iptables working, but if you're looking for a real-time monitoring tool, there's always [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/news.php) or possibly [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/).

As far as making iptables a bit easier, there are a bunch of iptables wrapper scripts that do a pretty good job. Here are a few of them:

- [Firehol](http://firehol.sourceforge.net/)
- [Arno's IPtables Firewall Script](http://freshmeat.net/projects/iptables-firewall/?topic_id=151)
- [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/)
- [Fwbuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/) (if you really, really need a GUI)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Vuurmurr:

http://www.vuurmuur.org/trac/

It's a ncurses based GUI that provides you with options to do traffic shaping.  It's built on top of iptables.